# Comment la construction « s'en tenir à » est-elle formée ?

Tags: sens, expressions, étymologie

Ayant trouvé cette expression dans [ces fils de discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=201437) sur Wordreference, [la définition du Larousse](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/se_tenir/77305/locution?q=tenir#175860) indique :

> **S'en tenir à quelque chose** = ne rien faire de plus, ne pas aller au-delà.

Plutôt que de seulement souscrire aux définitions, comment décomposer « *s'en tenir à* » pour parvenir à ce sens inespéré  ?

J'avais pensé à **s'en tenir à = *se tenir* à qqch de qch**. Quel serait le sens de [*se tenir*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/se_tenir/77305?q=tenir#76390) qui a donné « *s'en tenir à* » ?

---

**Supplément suite à la réponse de ex-user2728 :**

1. Dans la dernière ligne, vous détaillez excellemment que :

   > **s'en tenir à** = se maintenir, **demeurer *en* un lieu**, figurativement EN rester ***à*** une idée.`

   Quel est l'antécédent de « EN » que j'ai mis en majuscules ?
2. Dans la ligne troisième avant la fin, vous énoncez que :

   > **"se tenir" ou "s'en tenir" à qqch** = ne rien faire ni vouloir de plus.

   Comment et pourquoi se tenir = s'en tenir à qqch ?
3. Votre 3e paragraphe sur les synonymes de « tenir », où provient-il ?

Comment: Les pronoms _en_ et _y_ (tout comme ceux des verbes pronominaux) servent souvent simplement de modificateur de sens.  Leur antécédent est alors souvent vague ou même inexistant et leur nouveau sens ou la nuance qu'ils apportent sans rapport clair avec leur fonction grammaticale.

Answer (score 2):

Il faut voir que "tenir" a bien d'autres sens que saisir.

C'est qu'il dérive du latin **tenere**, qui signifie certes "avoir à la main", mais a aussi de nombreux autres sens :

comprendre (idée), diriger (bateau), posséder, être maître de, captiver, contenir, **maintenir, ne pas laisser échapper**, conserver, se souvenir de, ne pas laisser prendre, prendre sur le fait, s'appliquer à, obliger, soutenir une opinion, **faire durer, persister, prendre racine**, retenir, empêcher.

"se tenir" ou "s'en tenir" à quelque chose, c'est ne rien faire ni vouloir de plus ;

"savoir à quoi s'en tenir", c'est être certain;

"s'en tenir à" est donc "se maintenir, **demeurer *en* un lieu**", figurativement en rester ***à*** une idée.

Comment: Plussoyé. Pourriez-vous répliquer à mon supplément dans mon OP, SVP ?

Answer (score 0):

Dans la définition que vous donnez,  " *s'en tenir à quelque chose* " est un verbe pronominal qui a le même sens que " *se contenter de  quelque chose* ".

Comment: Merci beaucoup. J'ai éclairci ma question. Je saisis la définition, mais je n'entrave ni comment le déduire/inférer ni comment le dépecer pour atteindre le sens de **s'en tenir à qqch**. C'est ce dernier duquel je m'enquiers.

Comment: Malheureusement, je ne comprends plus très bien le sens de votre question.

Comment: Plussoyé pour votre peine. Stéphane Gimenez l'a chaleureusement amendéé. Voudriez-vous plus d'éclaircissement sur l'acception de ma question ?